# How to refer to a declared INTEGER in sql server

Tags: sql-server

This might be a simple question:
I would like to refer to a DECLARED variable in sql server. 
I have the following code:

```
DECLARE emp_id integer
SET emp_id=2083
GO
SELECT @emp_id;
```

It sould return a 1x1 table. 
However it is instead throwing me the following error

**[2018-06-27 17:09:40] [S0002][155] 'integer' is not a recognized CURSOR option.**

Comment: It should be `DECLARE @emp_id INT; SET @emp_id = 2083` (or in one go as `DECLARE @emp_id INT = 2083`). And you cannot use `GO` here, as 1) it's not a T-SQL command but a batch separator only recognized by `sqlcmd` and compatible; and 2) variable scope is restricted to batches, so after the `GO` `@emp_id` is no longer available.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Would you be willing to put that in an answer?